# Displaying links to other profile pages, while maintaining good white space

Tags: website-design, gui-design, interaction-design, design-patterns, user-profile

I am designing a profiles page for a website where the names and positions of company employees should be displayed on all profile pages for easy navigation.

[image: Image Here]

I do not want to put a `<ul>` to the left of the image, because that would likely make the page a bit busy. The other option I am thinking is to use a marquee, but that also seems to break down sometimes.

My question is, how can I put well designed links on that page sample while maintaining a good balance of white space.

Comment: What are the links to, and what is the purpose behind them?

Comment: @JohnGB the links are to other profile pages. Assuming you are on the profile page of the CEO, there will be other links to the profile pages of other staff members. I'm am thinking this will help in navigation.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have a link back to a page showing pics and summary information on all the staff members?

Comment: Is the design trying to show who is working under who? Like how management is structured?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say you should implement a landing page for profiles, since the profile page should only show the profile and things related to that profile. The only possible valid profile links would be a small organizational browser to see the current profiles colleagues, managers and subordinates.

The profile landing page could display both a organizational browser and a profile search. That way the implementation would be scalable, which your initial design isn't.

## Example of Organizational Browser

[image]

Comment: This is an awesome example. thanks for sharing this.